# UserControl IsPressed gives nothing back

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, user-controls

I created UserControl(Button) in Expression Blend

XAML:

```
<UserControl
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
x:Class="Marica.FullClient.Graphics.Node"
x:Name="UserControl" Height="360" Width="500" Margin="40">

<UserControl.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Grid>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.StrokeThickness)" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle">
                                            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
                                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Rectangle x:Name="rectangle" Stroke="Red" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True"/>
                        <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="True"/>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" TargetName="rectangle" Value="13"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" TargetName="rectangle" Value="13"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Button Name="NodeButton" Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyle1}"/>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <TextBlock
        x:Name="NodeName"
        x:FieldModifier="public"
        Text="Property"
        Margin="8,100,8,8"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        TextWrapping="Wrap" 
        TextAlignment="Center"
        FontFamily="Segoe Print"
        FontWeight="Bold" 
        Foreground="White"
        FontSize="50"/>

        <TextBlock
        x:Name="CategoryName"
        x:FieldModifier="public"
        Text="Property"
        Margin="8"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Center"
        TextWrapping="Wrap" 
        TextAlignment="Center"
        FontFamily="Segoe Print"
        FontWeight="Bold" 
        Foreground="White"
        FontSize="25"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

When I hoovered it over the control, the stroke width becomes bigger, but when I click, nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect that on IsPressed you wanted to do the Easing animation, and it does not appear to be working. Well, good news, your animation fires fine, you just need to tune it to do what you want in order to see that it's actually working. Play with KeyTime and Value

For example, change it to:

```
<EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02" Value="30" />
```

and you will see it starting to work/do more

Comment: Is there a way to keep button in that state? So that stroke thickness once the button have been clicked keeps i.e. 30 ?

Comment: Ok, i solved that. I've just replaces Button with Checkbox cause Button is not appropriate control :)

Comment: sorry, just saw your comments, looks like things are working though, good luck